# SSIS Oracle connector

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2019

I am in the process of setting up a new SQL server 2019 standard edition. (due to price unable to go to enterprise edition)
The issue I am having is I have re-written a SSIS package that uses an oracle connector within the package to push data into my SQL server tables.

However when I run this in SSMS it returns an obvious error:
[image]

I have also tried to run this via CMD line however returns the same error.

My query is there a way for me to auto extract data from an oracle DB using SQL server 2019 Standard edition.

Due to license restriction we are unable to have VS installed on the server.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: There are many ways to load data out of Oracle and into SQL without SSIS. It depends on the complexity of your data engineering needs. You could for example use powershell to extract an Oracle table and load it into SQL

Comment: You could also use a seperate process to export Oracle data as flat files then load those flat files into SQL. How frequently do your SSIS packages run? how much data do they load? Are you doing full or incremental loads? Are you doing any transformation of data?